# vuetify and font awesome wont work on test server but local it is working

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, font-awesome

**Environment**

- Vuetify Version: 2.1.11
- Vue Version: 2.6.11
- Font awesome Version: 5
- OS: macOS

**Steps to reproduce**
Followng guide docs does not result in a working v-icon

**Expected Behavior**
font awesome icons should show up when using vuetify

**Actual Behavior**
font awesome icons does show up when using vuetify local PC but not in develop/test server

```
 <v-list-item
                v-for="navigationItem in allowedNavigationConfigItems"
                :key="navigationItem.id"
                :to="navigationItem.routeConfig"
                data-spec-class="TheNavigationDrawer-ListItem"
                :data-spec-id="`TheNavigationDrawer-ListItem@${navigationItem.id}`"
                link
                @click=""
            >
                <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon> fa-fw {{ navigationItem.icon }}</v-icon>
                </v-list-item-icon>

                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title> {{ navigationItem.name }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>

                <v-list-item-action v-if="navigationItem.badgeCondition">
                    <BaseBadgeNotify :is-visible="student.newQuestionsToAsk" :is-inline="true" />
                </v-list-item-action>
            </v-list-item>
navigationConfigItems() {
        return [
            {
                id: 'news',
                icon: 'fa-newspaper',
                name: this.$t('mainNavigation.news'),
                badgeCondition: false,
                routeConfig: {
                    name: 'newsIndex',
                },
            },
            {
                id: 'canteen',
                icon: 'fa-utensils',
                name: this.$t('mainNavigation.canteen'),
                badgeCondition: false,
                routeConfig: {
                    name: 'canteenIndex',
                },
            },
            {
                id: 'planning',
                icon: 'fa-project-diagram',
                name: this.$t('mainNavigation.planning'),
                badgeCondition: this.areQuestionBadgeVisible,
                routeConfig: this.planningRouteConfig,
            },
            {
                id: 'timetable',
                icon: 'fa-table',
                name: this.$t('mainNavigation.timetable'),
                badgeCondition: false,
                routeConfig: {
                    name: 'timetablePage',
                },
            },
            {
                id: 'performance',
                icon: 'fa-tachometer-alt',
                name: this.$t('mainNavigation.performance'),
                badgeCondition: false,
                routeConfig: {
                    name: 'performancePage',
                },
            },
            {
                id: 'progress',
                icon: 'fa-tasks',
                name: this.$t('mainNavigation.progress'),
                badgeCondition: false,
                routeConfig: {
                    name: 'progressPage',
                },
            },
            {
                id: 'advice',
                icon: 'fa-comments',
                name: this.$t('mainNavigation.advice'),
                badgeCondition: false,
                routeConfig: {
                    name: 'advicePage',
                },
            },
        ];
    }
@import "helper";
@import "vuetifyCustomisations";
@import "fonts";
@import "../scss/fontawesome.scss";
@import "../scss/solid.scss";
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWn1q.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl6Ti.png

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#font-awesome-5-icons), you should either use a `<link>` inside your `public/index.html`

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or use the NPM package

```bash
$ npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free -D
```

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'fa',
  },
})
```

Your code does not look as any of these 2 cases. Which guide did you follow? The official one?

Comment: did not do the trick. still not working

Comment: Can you demonstrate that it does not work on CodeSandbox?